# Azure Data Lake suspended the use of .NET assemblies from within U-SQL scripts

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

Just got this message from Azure Data Lake Analytics when trying to submit a U-SQL job. Is this happening for everybody? Has this happened before?

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> We have temporarily suspended the use of .NET assemblies
>   from within U-SQL scripts. You will be able to use such assemblies
>   again in a few days. All other U-SQL and Azure Data Lake features are
>   available for your use.

Comment: What region? Are you using any tools to submit the job or are you using the portal? I have to troubles using the West Europe region / visual studio submitted job. Does it fail when submitting or when it is being executed?

Comment: **Region**: East US 2. **Method**: The job was submitted directly via the Azure Portal. Previously successful jobs that referenced assemblies are now failing.

Comment: Just spun up instances of Azure Data Lake Store/Analytics in the **North Europe** region, same issue.

Comment: My first comment has a small typo, should be :   have **no** troubles using the West Europe region / visual studio submitted job. What assemblies are you using? I tested the [Newtonsoft.Json] and [Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats] assemblies

Comment: The same two. I was under the impression ADL is only available in three regions - Central US, East US 2 & North Europe? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/regions/services/

Comment: I am using a preview account, assigned upon request. That might be the difference. But one would assume it would be broadly communicated if they had planned this. Maybe reach out to there support team?

Comment: I'm not on a support plan at the moment. Have asked @AzureSupport for assistance but were no help. Would be interested to know if anyone else is seeing this?

Comment: Just created a brand new account and the issue remains. Quite surprised this is not more of a problem? Would appreciate it if anyone else with a standard Azure account is able to use .NET assemblies at the moment in there Azure Data Lake Analytic jobs (e.g. https://www.taygan.co/blog/2018/01/06/azure-data-lake-series-working-with-json-part-1).

Comment: Created a new account in Norht Europe and it works as expected. If it is still not working for you, can you post (the relevant portion of) your u-sql script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First let me address the inability to execute code from assemblies, e.g., the error message

```
We have temporarily suspended the use of .NET assemblies from within U-SQL scripts. You will be able to use such assemblies again in a few days. All other U-SQL and Azure Data Lake features are available for your use.
```

We are doing some maintenance that requires us to turn off assembly support on non-EA accounts. The maintenance is being rolled out by region, so some regions may already have the maintenance completed. We hope that it completes the latest early this week (goal is to be done over the weekend).

I am not sure why there was no clearer communication been done. I will check.

As to the Western EU region: That is a preview region for testing some new capabilities. If you are interested in this, please contact me offline.

**UPDATE Monday: The maintenance has been completed and all .NET assembly usage should be supported again on all accounts in all regions.**

Comment: Thanks Michael. Will wait till then.

Comment: The maintenance has been completed earlier today.